# Run roscore from python

Tags: python, ros-kinetic, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to automate the launch of multiple nodes with the [roslaunch API](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/API%20Usage).
So far, I am able to do what I want, and my nodes are running perfectly. (I am also able to stop them).

**Now, I noticed that the roslaunch API doesn't work if no roscore is running (in a terminal).**.

So I am trying to start the roscore at the beginning of my script (before starting my nodes).
What I tried so far (also described [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/215600/how-can-i-run-roscore-from-python/?answer=223264#post-id-223264)) is:

```
import subprocess
roscore_process = subprocess.Popen('roscore')
```

However, I am unable to stop the roscore process with `roscore_process.kill()`.

It seems that the `roscore` program creates a parent process that spawns multiple children processes (i assume: rosmaster, parameter server, rosout...). This can also be seen with `top` or `htop`. Therefore calling `roscore_process.kill()` only kills one of the children.

Do you have any idea on how to start **and stop** a roscore ?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289514/run-roscore-from-python/) by [ejalaa12](https://answers.ros.org/users/33860/ejalaa12/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2018-04-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Haaa !

After digging in the [documentation of the roslaunch API](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/roslaunch/html/roslaunch.parent.ROSLaunchParent-class.html), I was able to find a solution.

The idea is to use a `ROSLaunchParent` which is used to start/shutdown `.launch` files. According to the documentation a `ROSLaunchParent` can be a `roscore` instance if the parameter `is_core` is set to `True`.

So here is my solution:

```
from roslaunch.parent import ROSLaunchParent

parent = ROSLaunchParent(run_id, [], is_core=True)     # run_id can be any string
parent.start()
# [... do other stuff ...]
parent.shutdown()
```

The trick is to pass an empty list of roslaunch_files, so that we just use the functionality of the class to start a roscore.

Hope this helps others :)

---

Originally posted by [ejalaa12](https://answers.ros.org/users/33860/ejalaa12/) with karma: 81 on 2018-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BatmanofZNA](https://answers.ros.org/users/145297/batmanofzna/) on 2023-04-13**:
This is the way. It worked for me